# Getting an alert to display blocking log in for a user with a certain permission level

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

I am trying to figure out how to block a user from signing in to my site unless they are over a certain permission level. I am making my site public and once someone registers they are given the permission level 'bench'. Once I change the permission level they are able to login. The way I am blocking the 'bench' permission level users is with a redirect to the index page(where they sign in at). However, I want to display some sort of alert that pop's up displaying a message that I create and then from the start not even allow that user to move forward.

Can I block the user in a validation?

This is how I allow the user to login..

```
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('userIndex.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

}

I then redirect like this...

```
if($user->hasPermission('bench')) {
    header("Location: http://sundayfundayleague.com");
    die();
}
```

This is my permissions code:

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As I said if there is anyway I can block the user from progressing at all from the start and then display the alert so they know why, that would be great.

Any ideas how I can do this or suggestions?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but your question needs more clarification.  For example, if a person hasn't signed in then how do you know who that person is or what permissions they have?  Do you mean a user who has registered but who is not yet approved?

Comment: Yes I mean a user has registered but has not been approved yet.

Comment: I'm not apposed to them logging in or it being checked. I just want the code to be killed there and thay alert to pop up so they know why they can't log in